# Elastic get relevant results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query that searchs in **title**, **description**, **author**, **ean**, **isbn**.

I have boosts for **title^3**, **author^2**, **ean^100** and **isbn^100**.

When I get hit with ean it returns only 1 result. (ean is a number)

ISBN is a string eg. **978-12-1234-123-8** and I get thousands of results for ISBN. But if there is hit the one will have marginally higher result then the others.

I'm using **multi_match** with type **best_fields**.

Is there a way to get only relevant results? Or I have to do it by myself?

EDIT:

Mappings:

```
"product": {
"properties": {
  "img": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "dobrovsky_rating": {
    "type": "float"
  },
  "isbn": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "saleType": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "rating": {
    "type": "float"
  },
  "description": {
    "analyzer": "hunspell_cs",
    "type": "string"
  },
  "availability": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "priceDph": {
    "type": "long"
  },
  "title": {
    "analyzer": "hunspell_cs",
    "type": "string"
  },
  "url": {
    "index": "not_analyzed",
    "type": "string"
  },
  "rating_count": {
    "type": "long"
  },
  "ean": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "serie": {
    "analyzer": "hunspell_cs",
    "type": "string"
  },
  "id": {
    "type": "long"
  },
  "category": {
    "analyzer": "hunspell_cs",
    "type": "string"
  },
  "authors": {
    "analyzer": "hunspell_cs",
    "type": "string"
  }
}
```

Data example:

```
Id: 123
Title: Game of Thrones
Author: George R.R. Martin
Img: www.aaa.cz/got.png
Url: www.aaa.cz/got.html
Description: Game of Thrones is a ...
EAN: 9788071974925
ISBN: 978-80-7197-492-5
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
POST /MyINdex/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "_source": {
    "include": [
      "*"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "978-12-1234-123-8",
      "fields": [
        "title^3",
        "author2^2",
        "ean^100",
        "isbn^100",
        "description^1"
      ],
      "default_operator": "and"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It works for ISBN. But author, title and description don't work properly.

Comment: Can you then post you mapping and example of documents?

Comment: First of all in mapping you authorS and in original question you posted author, second it doesnot work on description because description is not included in fields

Comment: @tttpapi I preffer to specify which fields i want to search. if you remove fields it will search on all of them but then you cant specifcy boosting.